# Quitar espacio en blanco antes del header xcode swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Actualmente tengo un problema en cuanto a como se visualiza un header en una pantalla especifica de xcode y swift 5.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se visualiza en la imagen, al inicio hay un espacio en blanco, y el header lo agrego en las coordenadas de siempre posicionándolo al inicio.

Aqui algunos fragmentos de mis clases.

```
import UIKit


class MyChatController : ChatViewController {

let screen:ScreenUtil = ScreenUtil();

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad();


    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.closeKeyBoard(_:)))

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

}

@objc func closeKeyBoard(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    self.resignFirstResponder()
    self.textViewDidEndEditing((self.inputToolbar?.contentView?.textView)!)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.view.frame = screen.frameFullScreen()
    super.viewWillAppear(animated);
    BaseController.showTopBarStatic(screen, vc: self);

    let logo = BaseController.addLogoStatic(screen, vc: self);
    logo.alpha = 0.95;
    insertBlurView(view: logo, style: .extraLight);

    BaseController.createMenuButtonStatic(screen, vc: self);

    navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false

    if let name = dialog.name {
        print("Chat Name: \(name)")
        addChatTitle(name);
    }else{
        addChatTitle("");
    }

    addBotonPersonas();

}

 func showTopBarStatic(_ screen:ScreenUtil, vc:UIViewController){
       let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: screen.w(50), height: 20));
       v.backgroundColor = COLOR_DEFAULT_1;

       vc.view.addSubview(v);
   }


 func createMenuButtonStatic(_ screen:ScreenUtil, vc:UIViewController){
    let image = UIImage(named: "menu-button");

    // arriba a la izquierda
    //let boton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(screen.x(2.5), screen.y(7.1), 24, 17));

    let boton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: screen.x(100)-40, y: screen.y(7.1), width: 25, height: 25));

    //let boton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(screen.x(2.5), screen.y(19), 32, 32));
    boton.setTitle("", for: UIControl.State());
    boton.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIControl.State());
    boton.addTarget(vc, action: #selector(BaseController.onTouchMenu), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside);

    vc.view.addSubview(boton);
}

func addChatTitle(_ titulo:String){

    let c = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 83,width: 320,height: 25));
    c.backgroundColor = ColorUtils.hexStringToUIColor(hex: COLOR_HEXA_VERDE_1);

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 320,height: 25));
    label.text = titulo;
    label.font = UIFont(name: label.font!.fontName, size: 14);
    label.textColor = UIColor.black;
    label.textAlignment = .center;

    c.addSubview(label);
    view.addSubview(c);
}




@objc func onTouchPersonas(_ boton:UIButton){
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue_integrantes", sender: self);

}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.destination.isKind(of: ListaIntegrantesController.self)){

        print("Prepare for segue")
        let c = segue.destination as! ListaIntegrantesController;

        //let task:BFTask = ServicesManager.instance().usersService.getUsersWithIDs(dialog.occupantIDs!);

            if(dialog.occupantIDs != nil){
                print("dialog.occupantIDs?.count \(String(describing: dialog.occupantIDs?.count))")
                //let users = ServicesManager.instance().usersService.usersMemoryStorage.users(withIDs: dialog.occupantIDs!)


               c.users = self.users

                /*var con: Any = QBChat.instance().contactList!.contacts as Any
                print(QBChat.instance().contactList!.contacts as Any)
                */
                /*if let user = ServicesManager.instance().usersService.usersMemoryStorage.userWithID(opponent) {
                    self.title = "\(user.fullName!)"
                }*/

                //c.usuarios = users;
            }
    }
}

}
```

La otra clase sería la siguiente, que proviene de una librería de Quickblox.

```
                    import CoreTelephony
                    import SafariServices

                    fileprivate func < <T : Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
                      switch (lhs, rhs) {
                      case let (l?, r?):
                        return l < r
                      case (nil, _?):
                        return true
                      default:
                        return false
                      }
                    }

                    // FIXME: comparison operators with optionals were removed from the Swift Standard Libary.
                    // Consider refactoring the code to use the non-optional operators.
                    fileprivate func > <T : Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
                      switch (lhs, rhs) {
                      case let (l?, r?):
                        return l > r
                      default:
                        return rhs < lhs
                      }
                    }


                    var messageTimeDateFormatter: DateFormatter {
                        struct Static {
                            static let instance : DateFormatter = {
                                let formatter = DateFormatter()
                                formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
                                return formatter
                            }()
                        }

                        return Static.instance
                    }


                    class ChatViewController: QMChatViewController, QMChatServiceDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, QMChatAttachmentServiceDelegate, QMChatConnectionDelegate, QMChatCellDelegate {


                        let maxCharactersNumber = 1024 // 0 - unlimited

                        var users:[Contacto]!
                        var dialog: QBChatDialog!
                        var willResignActiveBlock: AnyObject?
                        var attachmentCellsMap: NSMapTable<AnyObject, AnyObject>!
                        var detailedCells: Set<String> = []

                        var typingTimer: Timer?
                        var popoverController: UIPopoverController?

                        lazy var imagePickerViewController : UIImagePickerController = {
                            let imagePickerViewController = UIImagePickerController()
                            imagePickerViewController.delegate = self

                            return imagePickerViewController
                        }()

                        var unreadMessages: [QBChatMessage]?

                        override func viewDidLoad() {
                            super.viewDidLoad()

                            //self.buscarUsuarios()
                            if let currentUser:QBUUser = ServicesManager.instance().currentUser {
                                self.senderID = currentUser.id

                                self.senderDisplayName = currentUser.login ?? ""

                                print("self.senderID : \(self.senderID)")

                                print("DisplayName : \(self.senderDisplayName)")


                                self.updateTitle()

                                self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                                self.inputToolbar?.contentView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                                self.inputToolbar?.contentView?.textView?.placeHolder = "Mensaje"

                                self.inputToolbar?.contentView.rightBarButtonItem.setTitle("Enviar", for: UIControl.State());
                                self.inputToolbar?.contentView.rightBarButtonItem.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: (self.inputToolbar?.contentView.rightBarButtonItem.titleLabel!.font!.fontName)!, size: 13);

                                self.attachmentCellsMap = NSMapTable(keyOptions: NSPointerFunctions.Options(), valueOptions: NSPointerFunctions.Options.weakMemory)

                                if self.dialog.type == QBChatDialogType.private {

                                    self.dialog.onUserIsTyping = {
                                        [weak self] (userID)-> Void in

                                        if ServicesManager.instance().currentUser.id == userID {
                                            return
                                        }

                                        self?.title = "Escribiendo"
                                    }

                                    self.dialog.onUserStoppedTyping = {
                                        [weak self] (userID)-> Void in

                                        if ServicesManager.instance().currentUser.id == userID {
                                            return
                                        }

                                        self?.updateTitle()
                                    }
                                }



                                if (self.storedMessages()?.count > 0 && self.chatDataSource.messagesCount() == 0) {


                                    self.chatDataSource.add(self.storedMessages())
                                }

                               self.loadMessages()

                                self.enableTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingAllTypes

                            }
                        }
                        func chatContactListDidChange(contactList: QBContactList!) {
                            for cont in contactList.contacts! {

                            }
                        }


                        func buscarUsuarios(){
                            SpringLoadingUtil.addLoading(view);


                            ChatService.getUsuariosQuick(personas: dialog.occupantIDs! ){
                                (respuesta, objeto) in


                                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                                    print("getUsuariosQuick")
                                    SpringLoadingUtil.hideLoading(self.view);
                                    print(objeto as Any)
                                    self.users = objeto;


                                });

                            }
                        }

                        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
                            super.viewWillAppear(animated)

                            ServicesManager.instance().chatService.addDelegate(self)
                            ServicesManager.instance().chatService.chatAttachmentService.addDelegate(self)


                            self.willResignActiveBlock = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] (notification) in

                                self?.fireSendStopTypingIfNecessary()
                            }
                        }

                        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
                            super.viewDidAppear(animated)

                            // Saving current dialog ID.
                            ServicesManager.instance().currentDialogID = self.dialog.id!

                        }

                        override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
                            super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

                            if let willResignActive = self.willResignActiveBlock {
                                NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(willResignActive)
                            }

                            // Resetting current dialog ID.
                            ServicesManager.instance().currentDialogID = ""

                            // clearing typing status blocks
                            self.dialog.clearTypingStatusBlocks()
                            ServicesManager.instance().chatService.removeDelegate(self)
                            ServicesManager.instance().chatService.chatAttachmentService.delegate = nil

                        }



                        deinit {

                            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
                        }

                        // MARK: Update

                        func updateTitle() {

                            if self.dialog.type != QBChatDialogType.private {

                                self.title = self.dialog.name
                            }
                            else {

                                if let recipient = ServicesManager.instance().usersService.usersMemoryStorage.user(withID: UInt(self.dialog!.recipientID)) {

                                    self.title = recipient.login
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        func storedMessages() -> [QBChatMessage]? {
                            return ServicesManager.instance().chatService.messagesMemoryStorage.messages(withDialogID: self.dialog.id!)
                        }

                        func loadMessages() {
                            // Retrieving messages for chat dialog ID.
                            guard let currentDialogID = self.dialog.id else {
                                print ("Current chat dialog is nil")
                                return
                            }

                            ServicesManager.instance().chatService.messages(withChatDialogID: currentDialogID, completion: {
                                [weak self] (response, messages) -> Void in

                                guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

                                guard response.error == nil else {
                                    SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: response.error?.error?.localizedDescription)
                                    return
                                }

                                if messages?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
                                    strongSelf.chatDataSource.add(messages)
                                }

                                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                            })
                        }

                        func sendReadStatusForMessage(message: QBChatMessage) {

                            guard QBSession.current.currentUser != nil else {
                                return
                            }
                            guard message.senderID != QBSession.current.currentUser?.id else {
                                return
                            }

                            if self.messageShouldBeRead(message: message) {
                                ServicesManager.instance().chatService.read(message, completion: { (error) -> Void in

                                    guard error == nil else {
                                        print("Problems while marking message as read! Error: %@", error!)
                                        return
                                    }

                                    if UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber > 0 {
                                        let badgeNumber = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber
                                        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeNumber - 1
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        }

                        func messageShouldBeRead(message: QBChatMessage) -> Bool {

                            let currentUserID = NSNumber(value: QBSession.current.currentUser!.id as UInt)

                            return !message.isDateDividerMessage
                                && message.senderID != self.senderID
                                && !(message.readIDs?.contains(currentUserID))!
                        }

                        func readMessages(messages: [QBChatMessage]) {

                            if QBChat.instance.isConnected {

                                ServicesManager.instance().chatService.read(messages, forDialogID: self.dialog.id!, completion: nil)
                            }
                            else {

                                self.unreadMessages = messages
                            }

                            var messageIDs = [String]()

                            for message in messages {
                                messageIDs.append(message.id!)
                            }
                        }
```

Anteriormente ese código funcionaba muy bien pero al actualilzar las librerías de Quickblox se empezó a visualizar de esa manera.

Aquí un ejemplo del método que se llama al crear un espacio para el header.

```
let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: screen.w(100), height: 20));
        v.backgroundColor = COLOR_DEFAULT_1;        
        vc.view.addSubview(v);
```

Aunque le digo las posiciones aún así como que el contenedor principal se baja.

Comment: El ejemplo es para crear un View, cómo utilizas Quickblox en ese ejemplo? Si cambias el height a 0 funciona?

Comment: La pantalla de quickblox no contiene nada, se construye con código, ese código es la clase ChatViewController